# how to write to a file in emacs

Tags: file, emacs, elisp

I want the emacs lisp code to append some data to a log file from emacs. The
log file is large so I don't want to read it into memory.

I just need to open the log file, append some data to it, close it.
I never need to see or manually edit the content.

Comment: Do you need to use emacs to perform this?  Couldn't you just use the redirect function (`>>`) to append the new data?

Comment: no I want to write an write-file-hook so that every time I write a file i append an entry to the log file

Answer (score 14):

You can use the `append-to-file` lisp function.

> Append the contents of the region to the end of file filename.
>   When called from a function, expects three arguments,
>   start, end and filename.  start and end are normally buffer positions
>   specifying the part of the buffer to write.
>
> If start is nil, that means to use the entire buffer contents.
>
> If start is a string, then output that string to the file
>   instead of any buffer contents; end is ignored.

More information is available [here](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Writing-to-Files.html)

Comment: I came across this two years after the fact and it was one of those "the thing you needed, emacs provided for you all along!" moments. Thank you.

Comment: I wanted to overwrite a file rather than append to the file. For this you can use (write-region "file-contents" nil "/tmp/file"). This incidentally also takes an append argument.

Answer (score 7):

```
(defun add-log-entry (log-message log-file)
  "Add a given message string to the end of a file."
  (append-to-file log-message nil log-file))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(f-write (format "%s" \<your list or what you what> ) 'utf-8\<or other encoding> "\<absolute file path>")
```

then go to the end of this line on closing braket and press C-e , go to the terminal cat + file, enjoy